# Need some clarification on something rather elementary about Ramsey Theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I am covering Ramsey Theory at this time while learning Combinatorics and I needed clarification on something.  Any help would be appreciated.

In the text, it states the following:
"We show that r(2,n) = n:

1. r(2, n) $\le$ n: If we color the edges of $K_n$ either red or blue, then either some edge is
   colored red (and so we have a red $K_2$) or all edges are blue (and so we have a blue
   $K_n$).
2. r(2, n) > n - 1: If we color all the edges of $K_{n-1}$ blue, then we have neither a red $K_2$
   nor a blue $K_n$." Since r(2,n)$\le$ n and r(2,n) > n-1, r(2,n) = n.

$K_n$ is a complete graph on n vertices. What I am confused about is the second part, if you color all the edges of $K_{n-1}$ blue, then you might not have a red $K_2$, but you have a blue $K_{n-1}$, and say for n-1 $\ge$ 2,  the blue $K_{n-1}$ would contain a blue $K_2$ as a subgraph.  And since r(2,n)=r(n,2), it shouldn't matter what we call blue and what we call red, it's arbitrary.  Maybe there's a flaw in my understanding but I would appreciate it if anyone could clarify this.

Comment: You're right that the situation is symmetric w/r/t red vs. blue; the proof simply picks one of them to focus on in one way and focuses on the other in a different way. You could reverse their roles without changing anything, but this argument *does* require you to pick a choice of roles in a sense. This may feel odd since we're somehow introducing structure we *don't* care about in order to prove something, but this is definitely legal (if sometimes unsatisfying).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: Thanks saulpatz.  I will update my post with MathJax.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Thanks for your response. If found my mistake. One of the lines in the text states "The existence of either a red $K_m$ or a blue $K_n$ is guaranteed,
no matter how the edges of $K_p$ are colored."  So if I can find a way to color the graph of $K_p$ such that there is no red $K_m$ and no blue $K_n$, then the ramsey number r(m,n) is not p.